# ObjectDatasource passing parameters

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I want to Insert data from textboxes using ObjectDatasource. The ObjectDataSource is bound to a gridview but displays certain computed columns only. The Textboxes are used to input all the basic inputs.
ObjectDatasource Delete & Select commands (Link buttons on  gridview)  are working. However I am having trouble with Insert command. I am not able to figure out how to pass the data from the textboxes as parameters to the ObjectDataSource Insert

EDIT: With the code below, a record is getting inserted. Parameters are getting passed. odssMain.Insert() gives the Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 
EDIT: WHY AM I GETTING THIS ERROR?

Also the ObjectDataSource has been acting weird. After an error, I have to reconfigure the Insert Method again on the ODS Wizard as the method will be blank.

ASP.NET 3.5 & SQL 2008, VS 2008.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsMain" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="SelectMain" DeleteMethod="DeleteMain" 
    InsertMethod="InsertMain" UpdateMethod="UpdateMain" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" TypeName="MainDB" >
.......
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
DAL FILE:
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert)]
public static int InsertMain(int Quantity)/
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    string strQuery = "INSERT INTO t_Main (Quantity) VALUES (@Quantity)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);

    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return i;
}

CODE BEHIND FILE:
protected void btnSaveAnalysis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    odsMain.InsertParameters.Clear(); 

    //Store parameters with values to the collection
    odsMain.InsertParameters.Add(new Parameter ("Quantity", TypeCode.Int32, iQuantity.ToString()));

    //Diferent ways that I tried. Still not working
    //odsMain.InsertParameters.Add("Quantity", iQuantity.ToString());
    //odsMain.InsertParameters["Quantity"].DefaultValue = iQuantity.ToString();

    odsMain.Insert();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try like this....

ObjectDataSource for InsertParameter looks like below one

```
<InsertParameters>
 <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />  
 <asp:Parameter Name="MiddleName" /> 
 <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />  
 <asp:Parameter Name="Desgination" />
 <asp:Parameter Name="Address" />  
 <asp:Parameter Name="City" />  
 <asp:Parameter Name="State" /> 
 <asp:Parameter Name="Country" /> 
</InsertParameters>
```

I will also pass InsertMethod  property of ObjectDataSource,which will have an InsertCustomer method.

InsertCustomer method looks like below one :-

```
   public void InsertCustomer(string FirstName, string MiddleName,string LastName, string Desgination, string Address, string City, string State, string Country)  
   {  

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCustomer", con);  
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

//this check is necessary, when u don't pass any value as it will pass as [default] and will give error

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
       FirstName = string.Empty;  
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))  
        LastName = string.Empty;  
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MiddleName))  
        MiddleName = string.Empty;  

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Desgination)) 
        Desgination = string.Empty;  

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))  
        Address = string.Empty;   

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))  
        City = string.Empty;  

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(State))  
        State = string.Empty;  

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))  
        Country = string.Empty;  

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_FirstName",  FirstName);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_LastName", LastName);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_MiddleName", MiddleName);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_Desgination", Desgination);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_Address", Address);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_City", City);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_State", State);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IV_Country", Country);  
    using (con)  
    {  

        con.Open();  
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }  

  }
```

Button Save for inserting record.

//Insert record Save Button

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{

     Customer.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtFirstName");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["MiddleName"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtMiddleName");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtLastName");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["Desgination"].DefaultValue= GetGridTextBoxValue("txtDesgination");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["Address"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtAddress");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["City"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtCity");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["State"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtState");  
    Customer.InsertParameters["Country"].DefaultValue = GetGridTextBoxValue("txtCountry");  
    Customer.Insert();  

 }
```

GetGridTextBoxValue function will get TextBox  text value from footer row of respective column.

//Get TextBox value of GridView Footer Row

```
public string GetGridTextBoxValue(string txtID)  
{
     try
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)gvCustomer.FooterRow.FindControl(txtID); // here you can place any text box value on your design page 
        return txt.Text;  

    }

    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        return string.Empty;
        throw ex;  
    }  

}
```

and the results  image [image] is like this ...

Comment: Yes I did see an example similar to this.

Comment: However, the line Customer.InsertParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = strFirstName was giving me a runtime error.